# remove words that begin with a !

Tags: java, regex

In a line, I want to remove any WORD that begins with a `!` (negation mark).

Can any one help me with the regular expression that I need to use for this in Java?

```
String line = "hello world hello2 !xxx hello3, %643,!xxxxxxx. world5, !";
String pure = line.replaceAll("?", "");
```

I want to remove all `!xxx` in that example.

Thanks!

Comment: This is what you want strip-words-beginning-with-a-specific-letter-from-a-sentence-using-regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188819/strip-words-beginning-with-a-specific-letter-from-a-sentence-using-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to remove all !xxx in that example.

Try:

```
String pure = line.replaceAll("!\\p{L}+", "");
```

`\p{L}` matches any unicode letter and `+` means 'one or more'.

A demo:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "!café hello world hello2 !xxx hello3, %643,!xxxxxxx. world5, !";
    String pure = line.replaceAll("!\\p{L}+", "");
    System.out.println(pure);
  }
}
```

which produces:

```
hello world hello2  hello3, %643,. world5, !
```

Comment: This fails on the last character.

Comment: @Rafe, the OP said "I want to remove all !xxx in that example". The last `!` is no such thing (it has no word after it), so IMO it should remain in there. Besides, how would you know exactly when something fails or not? I mean you're not the one asking the question, right?

Comment: Bart ... this works great!  Thanks a lot.  I only need to remove the word if there is a ! before it.

Answer (score 2):

`/!\w*/`

or maybe

`/!\w+/`

Comment: @hese, this works only for the ASCII characters a-z and A-Z, not for unicode or extended ascii chars. SO if you're onlu worried about ascii, this is the way to go, else, replace `\w` with `\p{L}`

Comment: yes, this didn't work since the text is unicode.  i am using \p{L}.

Comment: Just as any code that writes `[a-z]` is almost certainly *ipso facto* broken, so too because of Java’s inherently idiotic an broken bustedness vis-à-vis `\w`, `\s`, and friends must be relegate all such uses into the same category: inherently broken.

Comment: @Bart: (just following up here) Although it may well be what is wanted, just swapping in `\pL` for `\w` isn’t the same, because the normal sense of `\w` is pretty broad, including not only letters `\pL` but also decimal numbers `\p{Nd}`, connector punctuation `\p{Pc}`, letter numbers `\p{Nl}`, diacritical marks `\pM`, and a few others.